# Create custom column mapping for java.time.LocalDate with Slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm using Slick 3.1.0-M2 and I wish to use the java.time.LocalDate and java.time.LocalTime in my tables. I do it like this:

```
import java.sql.{Date, Time, Timestamp}
import java.time.{LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime, ZoneOffset}

trait DateTimeColumns {

  import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._

  implicit val localDateTimeColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDateTime, Timestamp](
    d => Timestamp.from(d.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(0))),
    d => d.toLocalDateTime
  )

  implicit val dateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDate, Date](
    d => Date.valueOf(d),
    d => d.toLocalDate
  )

  implicit val timeColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalTime, Time](
    localTime => Time.valueOf(localTime),
    time => time.toLocalTime
  )
}
```

So I have 3 implicit mappings but only the first one compiles. The ones with java.sql.Date and java.sql.Time fails the compilation with:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type slick.driver.PostgresDriver.BaseColumnType[java.sql.Date]
```

When I do a implicit parameter inspection in IntelliJ I can see that the first mapping finds TimestampJdbcType in the file JdbcTypesComponent.scala. Right next to that I see the TimeJdbcType and DateJdbcType. So how come the first one is found but the others aren't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check the **`slick.driver.JdbcTypesComponent`**, you will find a **`trait ImplicitColumnTypes`** contains lots of implicits for column type, including:

```
implicit def timeColumnType = columnTypes.timeJdbcType
implicit def dateColumnType = columnTypes.dateJdbcType
```

The latter two you defined actually **have the same name** with the default ones.

Changing the name of them or renaming the default ones when importing works for me.

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api.{ timeColumnType => DefaultTimeColumnType }

implicit val myDateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDate, Date](
    ld => Date.valueOf(ld),
    d => d.toLocalDate
)

implicit val timeColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalTime, Time](
    localTime => Time.valueOf(localTime),
    time => time.toLocalTime
)
```

Comment: Ahh, I don't think I ever would have found this error, so a BIG thank you! :)